# How to draw a stacked barplot with three categorical variables representing the proportion of only one of them for each facet in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stack, bar-chart, prop

This is the data to take up as a reference

`df <- data.frame(a = c(3,3,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,3), b = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2), c = c(4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2) )`

I want to draw a bargraph with the proportion of a for each facet. At the same time I want the bars to be colored according to the b value. 
The variable b is not relevant for calculating the percentage. This is what I came up with, when I set the fill = c, it divides the stacked color in two, one corresponding to 1, and the other as NA.

```
      ggplot(aes(x = a, y = ...prop..., group = 1, fill = b)) +
          geom_bar(position = "stack") +
          facet_wrap(~c, nrow = 1, ncol = 5) +
          labs(title = "Count of a among c")
```

[image]

how can I have a result similar to this one but with the proportions of a for each facet wrap instead of the absolute values?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried constructing a proportions variable and then using that in the plot?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but since I am mostly working with igraph objects with a large amount of variables and I need a light code, I wondered if there was a solution maintaining the df as it was. As it turned out, thanks to Ian response, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using the `..count..` and `..PANEL..` special symbols:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = a, fill = as.factor(b))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.. / tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) +
  facet_wrap(~c, nrow = 1, ncol = 5) +
  labs(title = "Count of a among c", fill = "b", y = "Proportion")
```

[image]
If you weren't using `facet_wrap` this would be trivial by setting `y = ..prop..`. However, `..prop..` is not caculated properly by facet. So, to get around this problem, we can use `tapply` and the `..PANEL..` special symbol to `sum` `..count..` only for that panel. The last `[..PANEL..]` is to subset the resulting vector.

The other issue you had was that `b` is class numeric, so you need to convert that to factor.